# Add created vertices to a list

Tags: python, scripting

My goal is to add every created vertice to a list.

```
import bpy
import bmesh
def add_vert(loc):
    bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(bpy.context.edit_object.data)
    v = bm.verts.new(loc)
    bm.verts.index_update()
    bm.verts.ensure_lookup_table()
    vertlist = []
    vertlist.extend([v])
    print(vertlist)
    return {v}
add_vert((1,1,1))
```

This is what I get as output: 
`[<BMVert(0x0000020E20C3CF20), index=12>]
[<BMVert(0x0000020E20C3CF58), index=13>]
[<BMVert(0x0000020E20C3CF90), index=14>]`

This is what I would like: `[<BMVert(0x0000020E20C3CF20), index=12>,<BMVert(0x0000020E20C3CF20), index=13>,<BMVert(0x0000020E20C3CF20), index=14>]`

Comment: Loading an edit mode bmesh, updating and reindexing it every time a new vertex is added is complete overkill.  Which is why I pointed out making [only one bmesh in this answer as a class property](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/107548/15543)  ... or pass the bm to the method.

Comment: What I want to do is change the color of each vertex in the list using Bgl and so I have to make and update the list while in edit mode.

Comment: Ok let's put it another way. Let's say you add 1000 verts to your list to display in bgl. I contend you can create the bmesh once, add 1000 verts then update once. via your method above you create 1000 bmeshes and update a 1000 times.

Comment: I’m just using this example of what I want to do so I can get right to the point. I plan on implementing this into what u showed me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your `vertlist` variable outside of the function. Currently, `vertlist` exists only within the scope of the `add_vert` function. You can either define it before hand:

```
vertlist = []
def add_vert(loc):
    ...
```

or add a `try` statement to check if `vertlist` already exists:

```
def add_vert(loc):
    ...
    try:
        vertlist
    except NameError:
        global vertlist = []
    ...
```